# Flask authentication decorators

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-httpauth

Currently I'm using two types of authentication in my API:

- Local user + Local password
- DB user + DB password

For this I want to define a decorator for each type. Example:

```
@authenticator.local_authentication
```

or

```
@authenticator.db_authentication
```

Currently I have a working version of the local authentication decorator.
I want to create one for `@authenticator.db_authentication`. I'm using Miguel's [post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask/page/7#comments) as reference to add db authentication support.

The example currently works with `HTTPBasicAuth`.

Seems to be I need to overwrite `auth.login_required` and `auth.verify_password` which need to be defined when using: `@auth.login_required` to handle authentication.

Ideally I want to define just something like this in my API methods:

```
@authenticator.db_authentication
def get(self):
 ...
```

This is the working code that requires modification:

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    """Validates username or password in database.

    :param username_or_token:
    :param password:
    :return: user
    """
    return authenticator.db_authentication(username_or_token, password)

class Status(Resource):
    """Used for verifying API status"""

    @auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        log.info(request.remote_addr + ' ' + request.__repr__())
        log.info('api() | GET | Received request for Status')
        response = json.dumps('Status: Hello %s!' % g.user.username)
        return Response(response, status=200, mimetype=settings.api_mime_type)

    @authenticator.local_authentication
    def post(self):
        log.info(request.remote_addr + ' ' + request.__repr__())
        log.info('api() | POST | Received request for Status')
        response = json.dumps('Status: POST. %s' % settings.api_ok)
        return Response(response, status=202, mimetype=settings.api_mime_type)
```

I want to change `@auth.login_required` to `@authenticator.db_authentication`

Example of  `@authenticator.local_authentication` in a different file below:

```
def check_auth(username, password):
    """ Basic authentication: local username and password.

    :param username:
    :param password:
    :return:
    """
    return username == settings.api_account and password == settings.api_password


def authentication_error():
    """
    Authentication error.
    :return:
    """

    response = jsonify({'message': "Authenticate."})
    response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = settings.api_realm
    response.status_code = 401
    return response


def local_authentication(f):
    """Decorator to check local authentication.
    :param f: A function
    :return: itself: Decorator check_credentials
    """

    @wraps(f)
    def check_credentials(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth:
            return authentication_error()

        elif not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authentication_error()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return check_credentials

def db_authentication(username_or_token, password):
    """First try to authenticate by token.

    :param username_or_token:
    :param password:
    :return: boolean
    """

    user = Model.ApiUsers.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    if not user:
        # Try to authenticate with database password.
        user = Model.ApiUsers.query.filter_by(username=username_or_token).first()
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True
```

Comment: I honestly don't fully understand what is the problem that you have, but if you want to support two types of authentication with Flask-HTTPAuth, then I recommend that you create two `HTTPBasicAuth` object, each with their own `verify_password` function. Then you can decorate your routes with one or the other according to your needs.

Comment: I also din't quite follow the question!